# Spring UnsatisfiedDependencyException 2

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I see other people have posted similar questions regarding the same project from YouTube but I have a slightly different problem. My problem is that I keep getting:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in file

Hello, I am trying to follow this tutorial on YouTube called Spring Boot Tutorial | Full Course [2022] [NEW] located at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U&t=3141s

Everything is going along fine until I get to StudentService and StudentRepository

The error I keep getting is Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentService'

Side Note: Should I troubleshoot from the top or bottom of the stack trace?

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::       (v3.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

2022-12-12T08:20:56.844-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 13088 (C:\Users\19163\Desktop\demo\target\classes started by 19163 in C:\Users\19163\Desktop\demo)
2022-12-12T08:20:56.854-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-12T08:20:57.617-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-12T08:20:57.697-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 60 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-12T08:20:58.272-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-12T08:20:58.283-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-12T08:20:58.284-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2022-12-12T08:20:58.396-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-12T08:20:58.397-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1447 ms
2022-12-12T08:20:58.593-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-12T08:20:58.668-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
2022-12-12T08:20:58.897-08:00  WARN 13088 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2022-12-12T08:20:59.042-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-12T08:21:00.466-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2edb2f8b
2022-12-12T08:21:00.468-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-12T08:21:00.599-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-12-12T08:21:01.117-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-12-12T08:21:01.131-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-12T08:21:01.270-08:00  WARN 13088 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController' defined in file [C:\Users\19163\Desktop\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\StudentController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in file [C:\Users\19163\Desktop\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\StudentService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.example.demo.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.Student
2022-12-12T08:21:01.271-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-12T08:21:01.273-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-12-12T08:21:01.441-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-12-12T08:21:01.443-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-12T08:21:01.457-08:00  INFO 13088 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-12T08:21:01.477-08:00 ERROR 13088 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController' defined in file [C:\Users\19163\Desktop\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\StudentController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in file [C:\Users\19163\Desktop\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\StudentService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.example.demo.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.Student
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-20221212.130302-27.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-20221212.130302-27.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-20221212.130302-27.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-20221212.130302-27.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-20221212.130302-27.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-20221212.130302-27.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in file [C:\Users\19163\Desktop\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\StudentService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.example.demo.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.Student
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.example.demo.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.Student
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.Student
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3-20221212.155846-51.jar:6.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
... 44 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

Things I have already tried:

1. I tried arranging the files and packages as they are in the video so EntityScan is not needed, no
   success
2. I tried putting all java files including the main class in the same package with no success
3. I tried updating the Maven Project but intellij ultimate will not update the maven repository
4. I tried putting DemoApplication in the main package called "com.example.demo" and all student
   related files in a subpackage called "com.example.demo.student" to use with EntityScan with no
   success
   Always get the same exact error

I am on a Windows 10 laptop, using Spring Boot 3.0, and IntelliJ Ultimate
Here is my pom.xml file

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 

com.example
demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Here is my current project structure
[image: Project Structure]
[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hello, I am trying to follow this tutorial on YouTube called Spring Boot Tutorial | Full Course [2022] [NEW] located at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U&t=3141s

Comment: the video is a "fake" :) ..while it states it is from 2022, it uses (official) spring boot starter with spring boot current version: 2.4 (which was released in Nov. 2020;)

Comment: fix probably: 1. remove eclipselink dependency 2. replace (all source code, text) occurences of `javax.persistence` with `jakarta.persistence` (rest of the tutorial could still hold;) (this and other(but not all!) `javax.` apis (significantly) changed with spring-boot-3/spring-6) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes

Comment: better than some obscure "video tutorial" (from in-official sources): the official docs/guides, blogs, youtube/twitter/tictoc... (most-up-to-date) channels! :) e.g. https://spring.io/guides#gs (and as a side note to a "beginner": prefer "release" version to "RC/SNAPSHOT" (bleeding edge:))